# How to cast a string to timestamp9

Tags: postgresql

I have strings like this: `'2022-02-28T04:45:37.123456789Z'`

Does anyone know why this fails:

```
select '2022-02-28T04:45:37.123456789Z'::timestamp9
```

SQL Error [22008]: ERROR: invalid input format for timestamp9, required format y-m-d h:m:s.ns +tz "2022-02-28T04:45:37.123456789Z"
Position: 8

whereas this is fine:

```
select '2022-02-28T04:45:37Z'::timestamp9
```

Comment: There is in the DB I use. It's probably this extension https://github.com/fvannee/timestamp9

Comment: PostgreSQL 12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-1.pgdg21.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0, 64-bit

Comment: I'm guessing it is looking for the string to be: `2022-02-28T04:45:37.123456789 +0000` per the error message: '... required format y-m-d h:m:s.ns +tz ...'.

Answer (score 0):

What I found, using [timestamp9](https://github.com/fvannee/timestamp9) extension.

```
create extension timestamp9 ;

select '2022-02-28T04:45:37.123456789Z'::timestamp9;
ERROR:  invalid input format for timestamp9, required format y-m-d h:m:s.ns +tz "2022-02-28T04:45:37.123456789Z"
LINE 1: select '2022-02-28T04:45:37.123456789Z'::timestamp9;

--What I thought would work, but didn't
select '2022-02-28T04:45:37.123456789 +0000'::timestamp9;
ERROR:  invalid input format for timestamp9, required format y-m-d h:m:s.ns +tz "2022-02-28T04:45:37.123456789 +0000"
LINE 1: select '2022-02-28T04:45:37.123456789 +0000'::timestamp9;

--What does work
 select '2022-02-28 04:45:37.123456789 +0000'::timestamp9;
             timestamp9              
-------------------------------------
 2022-02-27 20:45:37.123456789 -0800

--A quick and dirty solution
select replace(replace('2022-02-28T04:45:37.123456789Z', 'T', ' '), 'Z', ' +0000')::timestamp9;
               replace               
-------------------------------------
 2022-02-27 20:45:37.123456789 -0800
```

Comment: The OP provided the link to the extension in a comment [github.com/fvannee/timestamp9](https://github.com/fvannee/timestamp9).